# How to accept additional parameter in subclass? (Without pylint's arguments-differ)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I have a base class that represents the state of a game and provides a `perform_move` method:

```
class GameState:
  # other code
  def perform_move(self, position: LinePosition) -> MoveResult:
    # more code
```

Now I want to create a subclass of `GameState` that keeps track of the players' score.
Because the base class doesn't care about players (separation of concerns), I need an additional argument to identify the player that is performing the move.
I tried the following:

```
class ScoreKeepingGameState(GameState):
  # other code
  def perform_move(self, position: LinePosition, *, player_identification: Optional[int] = None) -> MoveResult:
    # more code
```

I expected this to work, since I can call `ScoreKeepingGameState`'s `perform_move` perfectly fine without the `player_identification`, alas pylint complains:

> W0221: Parameters differ from overridden 'perform_move' method (arguments-differ)

Is there a cleaner approach to satisfy pylint than adding `# pylint: disable=arguments-differ` to the `perform_move` definition of `ScoreKeepingGameState`?

Comment: It does seem like a bug because the docs say "Extra arguments with default values are ignored." which they are clearly ... not.

Answer (score 3):

There's some quick and direct ways, and then there's the way where you rethink the design and use of inheritance.

The quick way: Make `perform_move` in the base class accept `*args` and `**kwargs` arguments; then the inheriting class also just accepts `*args` and `**kwargs` and it all will work. I don't like it that much because we lose the function signature that way, but it will make pylint stop complaining.

The longer way: If `GameState` shouldn't concern itself with player scores, then I assume it has some other single responsibility. Subclasses of `GameState` will still have that same responsibility; they're just fulfilling it in a different way. But now you also make it responsible for calculating and keeping track of the player's score. At least I assume that's what the overriden version of `perform_move` is supposed to do.

So maybe you want a separate class `ScoreKeeper` just for tracking score, and it shouldn't inherit from `GameState`.

Then you'd have a class responsible for "handling" player moves. This class would communicate separately with `GameState` to tell it about the line position and with `ScoreKeeper` to tell it about the player.